# Django Directory Structure

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I am new to learning Django and I know how important setting up an application directory structure can be for future additions.

At the moment, I am creating an API using the Django REST Framework and have a few questions on how to structure a Django project for future success.

I want the API to feed out possibly in the future to other outside sources that may need to grab data. I also will be building a front-end CRUD like system to display and update data.

How would you suggest structuring the directories in the future possibility of adding more front-end like systems that are all powered by the Data API?  Doing some research already, it seems like these are possibilities I have seen.

```
project
  manage.py
  project
    settings.py
    urls.py
  api
    models.py
    serializers.py
    views.py
  crudapp
    files here...

project
  manage.py
  project
    settings.py
    urls.py
    api
      models.py
      serializers.py
      views.py
  crudapp
     files here...

project
  manage.py
  project
    settings.py
    urls.py
  crudapp
     api
       models.py
       serializers.py
       views.py
     files here...
  futureapp
     api 
       models.py
       serializers.py
       views.py
     files here...
```

I am really trying to understand how Django and Python should have these modules setup. If I have separate modules/apps setup, they can all access the models in the API app for any sort of app I build in the future?

Any clarification or experience on this would be greatly appreciated. The main goal is to have an API for the data in the database, and to then be able to build a front-end CRUD to update and pull that data, with the possibility that more front-end type apps could be built in the future as the data set grows.

For example, I am building a corporate data CRUD system to store important corporate information that will be accessible by a front-end and also an API that can feed to other non DJANGO websites.  In the future, I may be adding an entirely different front-end/back-end CMS type system for a single page application.  However, some of the data in the database from the corporate data set may be used to populate the website data.

Comment: it's depends on your project size and mostly your personal opinions, try checking some django project structures on github, the choose something that feels better for you

Answer (score -1):

i would take structure like this:

```
project
    manage.py
    apps
        crudapp
        futureapp1
        futureapp2
```

so you can add as many apps as you wish and main project folder doesnot grow

and one more advantage is, your imports will be more beautiful and less name clashing in APPS:

`from project.apps.crudapp.models import OneModel`

```
# settings
INSTALLED_APPS = (
   'project.apps.crudapp',
)
```